# Import data and Call function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I use the function "is_double_url" to check 700 data that saved in the file name "training_URL", I can only check the data in cmd window or type "is_double_url('www.google.com')" in f10.m. But i want to use the import data as shown below to call out the function and check the 700 data

is_double_url.m file

```
function out = is_double_url(url_path1)

if url_path1(end)~='/'
url_path1(end+1)='/';
end

url_path1 = regexprep(url_path1,'//','//www.');
url_path1 = regexprep(url_path1,'//www.www.','//www.');

f1 = strfind(url_path1,'www.');
if numel(f1)<2
out = false;
else
f2 = strfind(url_path1,'/');
f3 = bsxfun(@minus,f2,f1');

count_dots = zeros(size(f3,1),1);
for k = 1:size(f3,1)
    [x,y] = find(f3(k,:)>0,1);
    str2 = url_path1(f1(k):f2(y));
    if ~isempty(strfind(str2,'..'))
        continue
    end
    count_dots(k) = nnz(strfind(str2,'.'));
end
out = ~any(count_dots(2:end)<2);

if any(strfind(url_path1,'://')>f2(1))
    out = true;
end
end

return;
```

f10.m file

```
url_path1 = importdata('DATA\URL\training_URL')
out = is_double_url(url_path1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the change in the numel(.) condition:

```
function out = is_double_url(url_path1)

if url_path1(end)~='/'
    url_path1(end+1)='/';
end

url_path1 = regexprep(url_path1,'//','//www.');

url_path1 = regexprep(url_path1,'//www.www.','//www.');

f1 = strfind(url_path1,'www.');
if numel(f1)>2                  % changed it here
    out = false;
else
    f2 = strfind(url_path1,'/');
    f3 = bsxfun(@minus,f2,f1');

    count_dots = zeros(size(f3,1),1);
    for k = 1:size(f3,1)
        [x,y] = find(f3(k,:)>0,1);
        str2 = url_path1(f1(k):f2(y));
        if ~isempty(strfind(str2,'..'))
            continue
        end
        count_dots(k) = nnz(strfind(str2,'.'));
    end
    out = ~any(count_dots(2:end)<2);

    if any(strfind(url_path1,'://')>f2(1))
        out = true;
    end
end

if ~out  % I'm not sure if this is what you want..
out=-1;
end

return;
```

Regarding the issue you mentioned in comments, let's say url_path1 is a cell array of size 700x1; then (I think) you could say

```
out=[];
for i=1:size(url_path1,1)
  out=cat(2,out,is_double_url(url_path1{i,1}));
end
```

Comment: it show me the same error "
??? Undefined function or method 'ne' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> is_double_url at 3
if url_path1(end)~='/'

Error in ==> f10 at 2
out = is_double_url(url_path1)"

Comment: If you try is_double_url('http://www.apple.com') it returns '1'. The problem you have I think is with the way you feed the 'is_double_url' function. Make sure in the main script 'url_path1' is actually a 'string' since your function 'is_double_url' is operating on that assumption. (I can't get that apple url right)

Comment: 'url_path1' is a file that contain 700 URLs line by line. any ideas how to modify it, i do need this urgently....and im beginner of matlab

Comment: Then you need to feed it into 'is_double_url' line by line or element by element. If 'url_path1' is cell array (which seems to be the case) extract each string from it and plug it into your function: is_double_url(url_path1{200,1}), is_double_url(url_path1{201,1}), etc (or {1,200}; perhaps in a 'for' loop).

Comment: the checking at here is correct, i do not have any ideas how to do the importdata and call the function out, i did it the same way for other features and it works. but, for the "is_double_url" not works when importing data.

Comment: Some functions are coded to work on arrays just fine, but the function you've defined yourself is taking a single string and acts upon that assumption.

Comment: I modified my answer, this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: which part to add the 'edited' answer, d '%change it here' comments there. I still get the error, may you modify and paste the whole answer which it works for you at there, because i do get error after modifying

Comment: No I mean from the _text_ 'regarding the issue you mentioned...' onwards (after the first bit of code). By the way, your function needs to check for more criteria, for example, this returns '1' while it shouldn't: is_double_url('http:.com')

Comment: my output is 1 or -1, if there is a double url then return 1 else -1, can you modify and update the latest version that can be run for u at there, because im confusing for now.

Comment: do u get to import and run for it?

Comment: Your function 'is_double_url in general' returns '1' or '0'. I don't have the data file you're working with, but suffice to say if 'url_path1' after import is actually a 700x1 cell array (you can check that by invoking 'whos url_path1'), then the 'for loop' I added at the end of the above answer should produce a cell array url_path2 of size 700x1 which contains either zeros or ones depending on each element of 'url_path1' and what your function returns for that element. If the check 'whos url_path1' return anything than a cell of strings of the size you want,

Comment: then you need to revise your 'importdata' step.

Comment: yes, now i want to change it to '1' or '-1'. the data file can simply take 5 URLs for samples in note pad (5x1). After that only i modify to 700x1, d step for my importdata is as above which works for other program. May you kindly modify and update the correct version, i need this urgently, thx~

Comment: I added something at the end of that code, hope this is what you have in mind.

Comment: then at f10.m, i change to "url_path1 = importdata('DATA\URL\training_URL')
out= is_double_url(url_path1{700,1})" right? at the end it return me out=1,

Comment: which means it works for call out right, juz my data is 700x1, may u try with 2 or 3 data with the method of import see...? i want the results in array form like [1 -1 -1 1 -1] if got 5 data.

Comment: I'm using the mobile app right know so I don't have access to matlab; but I modified what you should probably have in f10.m. See the answer above; that will give you an array 'out' of the form you want.

Comment: yes, this is the answer....n d last part, d output is inverse with '1' and '-1', may you edit for it ...thx~ i want is double url only return 1 else -1, the results is inverse. because this is i take from some 1 else and modify it, not i write by my own

Comment: the function 'is_double_url' as it is above should give you the correct (and opposite) output. At any rate, if you're looking for the opposite output, just do this in f10.m: out=-out;